# How to addClass as per the link content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one content page where there are links to different documents like .doc, .docx, .ppt .pptx, .txt.

I want to apply/add class dynamically not manual. like as per the link content.

```
<h3><a href="document.pdf" class="pdf-file">Document.pdf</a></h3>
.pdf-file {
background:url(../images/pdf-file.png) right center no-repeat; padding-right:18px;
}
```

This is manual class I applied.

jQuery solution will be prefered.

If you like my Question fav it. :)
thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[@href$=".pdf"]').addClass('pdflink');
  $('a[@href$=".doc"]').addClass('doclink');
  $('a[@href$=".docx"]').addClass('docxlink');
  $('a[@href$=".ppt"]').addClass('pptlink');
  //etc
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for, but why not do this:

```
a[href*=".pdf"].icon {
    background:url(../images/pdf-file.png) right center no-repeat; padding-right:18px;
}
```

This way you don't technically need to use JavaScript, the CSS is intelligent enough to interrogate the `href` attribute and apply the appropriate CSS properties.

Consider having a [look at this article](http://www.psyked.co.uk/css/auto-matic-link-icons.htm).